# How to clear input fields after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to clear the input fields after submitting the form, but the input data is still there, even after submitting the form every time. I am using `ajax jquery` form. How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

**Code**

```
function sendContact() {
  var valid;
  valid = validateContact();
  if (valid) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "contact_mail.php",
      data: 'userName=' + $("#userName").val() +
        '&userEmail=' + $("#userEmail").val() + '&subject=' + $("#subject")
        .val() + '&content=' + $("#content").val() + '&captcha=' + $("#captcha").val(),
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        $(".mail-status").html(data);
      },
      error: function() {}
    });
  }
}

function validateContact() {
  var valid = true;
  $(".demoInputBox").css('background-color', '');
  $(".info").html('');

  if (!$("#userName").val()) {
    $("#userName-info").html("(required)");
    $("#userName").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
  }
  if (!$("#userEmail").val()) {
    $("#userEmail-info").html("(required)");
    $("#userEmail").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
  }
  if (!$("#userEmail").val().match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/)) {
    $("#userEmail-info").html("(invalid)");
    $("#userEmail").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
  }
  if (!$("#subject").val()) {
    $("#subject-info").html("(required)");
    $("#subject").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
  }
  if (!$("#content").val()) {
    $("#content-info").html("(required)");
    $("#content").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
  }
  if (!$("#captcha").val()) {
    $("#captcha-info").html("(required)");
    $("#captcha").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
  }

  return valid;
}

function refreshCaptcha() {
  $("#captcha_code").attr('src', 'captcha_code.php');
}
```

**php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST["captcha"]==$_SESSION["captcha_code"]){
$toEmail = "web.instamarc@gmail.com";
$mailHeaders = "From: " . $_POST["userName"] . 
"<".  $_POST["userEmail"]    .">\r\n";
if(mail($toEmail, $_POST["subject"], $_POST["content"], $mailHeaders)) {
print "<p class='success'>Email Sent Successfully</p>";
} else {
print "<p class='Error'>Problem in Sending Mail.</p>";
}
} else {
print "<p class='Error'>Enter Correct Captcha Code.</p>";
}
?>
```

**Html**

```
<div id="frmContact">
<div class=row>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div id="mail-status"><?php echo $result; ?></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<span id="userName-info" class="info"></span>
<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" class="form-control"  
placeholder="Name">

</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<span id="userEmail-info" class="info"></span>
<input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" 
class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<span id="subject-info" class="info"></span>
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" 
class="form-control"  placeholder="Phone Number">
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<span id="content-info" class="info"></span>
<textarea name="content" id="content" 
class="form-control" 
placeholder="Your message" cols="60" rows="6">    </textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<span id="content-info" class="info"></span>
<input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" 
placeholder="Captcha"  class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 capcha">
<img id="captcha_code" src="captcha_code.php" />
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<button name="submit" 
class="border-button" onClick="sendContact();"> Send </button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The html code is missing. Forms can be resetted with: "document.getElementById("myForm").reset();"

Comment: Please show your HTML, otherwise we can't assist you.

Comment: Just use white out. Duh? :P

Comment: please add html code, it will be helpful.

Comment: It is not having form, it only has input tag and text field , i think i need to edit my answer :P

Comment: @ManuKrishna - see my answer

Comment: @ManuKrishna: have you seen my edit?, use  `$(".form-control").val("")` , it will reduce the code size :) Let me know if it works.

Comment: @hitesh : Showing an error 'Problem in Sending Mail' ,

Comment: @ManuKrishna - Can you remove reset code and run again and check if email sending is working

Comment: @ManuKrishna-  can you add this `print_r(mail($toEmail, $_POST["subject"], $_POST["content"], $mailHeaders)); exit ;` before your `if condition` in `php`, post the response, you are receiving here

Comment: @hitesh when i reset the code, the mail function running well. Can I add this line in fresh code ?

Comment: I added the code in php. But not working, the form responding nothing

Comment: @ManuKrishna : you need to debug it in php code. if it is not working when you are adding  the php code. Just check if the mail value is being passed before passing it to `php mail() function`

Comment: I am new in PHP, how can i check that?

Answer (score 2):

You are to clear the fields thru JavaScript. I see you are using jQuery so you can do:

```
    $("#userName, #userEmail").val("")
```

In your function would be:

```
//..Ajax function
success: function(data) {
    $(".mail-status").html(data);
    $("#userName, #userEmail").val("")
  },
```

And so forth.

I suggest using a FORM tag and you can easily reset it by doing:

```
$('#myformid')[0].reset();
```

Comment: but he is having more fields, you are only resetting the username and useremail.

Comment: I think he can use the class name, instead of writing it for all ids. `$(".form-control").val(" ")` . But anyways both ways are right ;)

Comment: The problem solved, but mail function not working now

Comment: I tried using form id also, but when I use form id mail is not sending

Comment: was it working before ?, can you try removing the code which you added for reset and try again

Answer (score 2):

You can use below three functions

```
/**
 * This function clear all input fields value including button, submit, reset, hidden fields
 * */

function resetForm(formid) {
 $('#' + formid + ' :input').each(function(){  
   $(this).val('').attr('checked',false).attr('selected',false);
 });
}


/**
 * This function clears all input fields value except button, submit, reset, hidden fields
 * */

function resetForm(formid) {
 $(':input','#'+formid) .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden') .val('') .removeAttr('checked') .removeAttr('selected');
 }

/**
 * This function clear all input fields value except button, submit, reset, hidden fields in different way
 * */

function resetForm(formid)
    { 

            form = $('#'+formid);
            element = ['input','select','textarea'];
            for(i=0; i<element.length; i++) 
            {
                    $.each( form.find(element[i]), function(){      
                            switch($(this).attr('type')) {
                                    case 'text':
                                    case 'select-one':
                                    case 'textarea':
                                    case 'hidden':
                                    case 'file':
                                            $(this).val('');
                                            break;
                                    case 'checkbox':
                                    case 'radio':
                                            $(this).attr('checked',false);
                                            break;
                                    case 'select':
                                           $(this).attr('selected',false);
                                    break;
                            }
                    });
            }

    }
```

**UPDATE** 
As per the html edit in the question below is my answer 
Use jQuery for resetting the fields

```
$(".form-control").val("")
```

**You need to use this function in ajax success**

```
   success: function(data) {
            $(".mail-status").html(data);
           // resetForm(formid); --> *Since you are not using any form , no need to use this function , use below line jQuery to do this reset.* 
            $(".form-control").val("")
          },
```

Comment: ;) :P Thanks @SpYk3HH

Comment: @SpYk3HH : If he adds html form in question, it will much easier to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery u can do like this

```
$("#userName").val("")  
$("#userEmail").val("")
$("#userEmail").val("")
$("#subject").val("")
$("#content").val("")
$("#captcha").val("")
```

Comment: you can combine all that into one call, fyi